# Android list view show it button visible and invisible?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am Android developer .I am used in json parser . i have to stored all data in Array List .What are the issue means i got custom id .They given 0 and 1 value passed.When i will get 0 means add button visible otherwise 1 will get in means custom button visible.How to check it in get View method.

I have added Array List   .

Comment: Is it home work for us or you have tried any thing.

Comment: post your getview() code

Comment: String value = arrListViewcustomoption_value.get(position);
    if(value.equals("1"))
    {
     holder.btn_add.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     holder.btn_custom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    
    else
    {
     holder.btn_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.btn_custom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

Comment: This is correct or not Muraliganesan?

Comment: use View.VISIBLE and View.GONE

Answer (score 1):

just use the condition something like below

```
if (yourvalue.equals("0")
{ 

button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{

button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code inside your get view method:

```
button.setVisibility((value==0)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
```